# Read column name definitions written in multiple lines from a table/view in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sqldatareader

I have `column names` something like this in a `view`.

```
SELECT
CAST(CONCAT('Trp', f.Production_disposal_Number, p.production_waste_number,p.production_shiftchange_number, t.production_unit_number,pr.process_unit_number,p.production_run_number  AS VARCHAR(50)) AS ProductionKey
,(SELECT MAX(v.LastModifiedDate) FROM (VALUES (p.LastModifiedDate), (f.LastModifiedDate), (p.LastModifiedDate), 
(d.LastModifiedDate), (pl.LastModifiedDate), (pr.LastModifiedDate), (t.LastModifiedDate)) AS vtable(LastModifiedDate)) 
AS LastModifiedDate
,CAST(p.Start_Date AS DATETIME2(0)) AS ProductionStartDate, CAST(p.End_Date AS DATETIME2(0)) AS ProductionEndDate
```

I want to retrieve these `column names` by the passing below `sql` query in my `C#` program

```
query=        
    "@DECLARE
     @olddelim nvarchar(32) = char(13) + Char(10),
     @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); 
     SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id('sge.vwProduct')),@olddelim, @newdelim), @newdelim);";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                        list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

This `code` runs fine only if all the `column names` are in single line. However, if the single column definition are written in multiple lines then it fails to read that `column name`. Also, if multiple column names are written in a single line, it doesn't read that as well.

For example, column name `LastModifiedDate` is neither identified nor read by program as it fails to identify start of the column definition. And in the same way `ProductionStartDate` is not read.

I want all `column names` be identified correctly and read by the program so that no column names are missed.

Comment: You want only a list of the names of the columns or a list of the complete definition for each column?

Comment: I would only need to retrieve all ```column names``` from a view

Comment: @stickybit bit I would only need to retrieve all column names from a view

Answer (score 0):

Change your query. You can easily query the column names of the view from the dictionary. There's no need to "parse" the create statement for that purpose.

```
SELECT c.name
       FROM sys.columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.views v
                       ON c.object_id = v.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
                       ON s.schema_id = v.schema_id
       WHERE s.name = 'sge'
             AND v.name = 'vwProduct'
       ORDER BY c.column_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a70f3eab8b38edd488d5982d4b5d8d70) (with different object names; but it should suffice as demonstration)

But be aware that `SqlDataReader` is disposable, so you should `Dispose()` it or use `using` like you did with the connection.

Comment: I want to modify this querystring as i pass this in my c# program        
    ```"@DECLARE
     @olddelim nvarchar(32) = char(13) + Char(10),
     @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); 
     SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id('sge.vwProduct')),@olddelim, @newdelim), @newdelim);";```

Comment: Yes, change it to the query I gave you in the answer -- `query = "SELECT c.name ... ";` -- and execute it like you do the other query now. The only thing I suggest to change in the rest of the code is to dispose the reader -- see the edit.

Comment: I have already included this querystring in the first part of the my program as ``` "queryString = @"SELECT c.[object_id],c.[name],c.column_id FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.views v ON c.object_id = v.object_id where v.name LIKE '%vw%'";``` and then established the sql connection and then passed the second query @Declare .....and established the sql connection. However the program reads the columns name definition only if written in one single line and doesn't the column names that are written in multiple lines. And yes i have used using System.Data.SqlClient